# Can you help me to formally define the phrase "to edit <something>"?

Tags: grammar

I am in a situation on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in which I dispute the validity of the system notification text "Code in your answer has been edited", because there was no code in the answer before the edit; merely, code was added to the answer *after* the edit.

Another user claims that this is simply a "more vague" meaning of "edit":

> Saying it was edited is not wrong, it's just more vague. [..] I'm asserting that your definition of "edited" is incorrectly narrow.

I'm fairly confident, though, that in the phrase "to edit *X*" the "*X*" is what was present *before* the edit, not as a result of it. That is, *you cannot edit something that is not there* by adding the thing.

However I'm struggling to find a way to prove it.

**How may I prove the following in a semi-formal manner?**

```
"Hi there."  => "Hi you."         # "I edited the second word".  <-- OK
"Hi there."  => "Hi there you."   # "I edited the third word".   <-- NOT OK
```

Comment: If you consult any dictionary, you will see *edit* defined as "to revise, correct, change". It is self-evident that you cannot change something that does not exist (yet). There is no way to prove what is evident. So perhaps you should just ignore those people and spend your time on something more interesting and important! With *in* it would be all right, as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, *The American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th edition, has this entry for *edit in* and *edit out*:

> **phrasal verbs:**  **edit in** To insert during the course of editing: *An additional scene was edited in before the show was aired.* **edit out** To delete during the course of editing; *A controversial scene was edited out of the film.*

So, you could, as Cereberus suggested in his comment, suggest that they *edited in* code to your answer. I personally would say they *added* code to your answer.

As for the system notification phrase in question, it's probably too cumbersome (or too sophisticated to expect) for an edit that includes an addition to be signaled with: "Code in your answer has been *edited in*."

Comment: And, of course, if there were to be *edited out* as well, then why not have just a single message, *has been edited* ?